# jQuery Move with scroll button of mouse, concrete peace of content

Tags: jquery, web

i have this statement of code for base logic and want to implement in my project:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#moveleft').click(function() {
    $('#textbox').animate({
    'marginLeft' : "-=30px" //moves left
    });
});
$('#moveright').click(function() {
    $('#textbox').animate({
    'marginLeft' : "+=30px" //moves right
    });
});
$('#movedown').click(function() {
    $('#textbox').animate({
    'marginTop' : "+=30px" //moves down
    });
});
$('#moveup').click(function() {
    $('#textbox').animate({
    'marginTop' : "-=30px" //moves up
    });
});
});
</script>
```

I want to modify this block of code, to can work with scroll button of mouse, if mouse scroll up to go up, and if scroll down to go down.

```
 <div id="rezitator" class="sticky row other black fade-in full_height">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="slider container-fluid"  id="slider">
          <div class="meta text-center">1 / 3</div>
            <div class="row">
              <a class="col-sm-1 slide_nav left-nav"><span>Before</span></a>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <img src="img/s/RT_Rezitator_01.jpg">
              </div>
              <a class="col-sm-1 slide_nav right-nav"><span>After</span></a>
            </div>
            <div class="description text-center">
              <p>Ryo Takeda liest Haruki Murakami im Übel &amp; Gefährlich<br /> Hamburg, November 2014</p>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <h1 class="text-center">Ryo Takeda liest</h1>
        <p class="h2">Einen Text laut zu lesen, heißt, ihn zum Leben zu erwecken. Es kann auch bedeuten, den Hörer in die Geschichte zu ziehen. Diese beiden Bewegungen ergeben eine spannende Atmos&shy;phäre. Ich erlebe das bei der kleinen intimen Lesung in einem Café, genauso wie auf der großen Bühne. Auch gelesen als Hörbuch nur für die eigenen Ohren bestimmt.</p>
        <a href="#">Referenzen</a>
      </div> 
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="redner" class="sticky row other fade-in full_height">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6" id="overflow">
        <h1 class="text-center">Ryo Takeda hält Reden</h1>
        <p class="h2">„Es braucht nicht viel, aber das wenige muss gut sein“ pflegt mein Vater zu sagen – anders ausgedrückt: Das gesprochene Wort muss gut gewählt sein. Oft fängt er mit einem kleinen Gedicht oder Zitat den Moment auf wunder&shy;bare Weise ein.</p>
        <p class="h2">In dieser Tra&shy;dition habe ich als freier Redner schon die unter&shy;schied&shy;lichsten An&shy;lässe be&shy;glei&shy;ten dürfen. Von runden Ge&shy;burts&shy;tagen und feier&shy;lichen Er&shy;öff&shy;nungen in Reim&shy;form bis hin zur freien Trau&shy;rede für Braut&shy;paar und Hoch&shy;eits&shy;gäste. Doch nicht nur die freudigen Er&shy;eig&shy;nisse des Lebens, auch die leisen und trau&shy;rigen Töne gehören natürlich dazu. JA-Wort geben, eine stande&shy;samtliche Ehe&shy;schließung ersetzt die freie Trauung allerdings nicht.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 fullBG" style="background-image:url(img/s/RT_Redner.jpg)">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I want only this to move up and down:

```
 <div class="col-md-6" id="overflow">
        <h1 class="text-center">Ryo Takeda hält Reden</h1>
        <p class="h2">„Es braucht nicht viel, aber das wenige muss gut sein“ pflegt mein Vater zu sagen – anders ausgedrückt: Das gesprochene Wort muss gut gewählt sein. Oft fängt er mit einem kleinen Gedicht oder Zitat den Moment auf wunder&shy;bare Weise ein.</p>
        <p class="h2">In dieser Tra&shy;dition habe ich als freier Redner schon die unter&shy;schied&shy;lichsten An&shy;lässe be&shy;glei&shy;ten dürfen. Von runden Ge&shy;burts&shy;tagen und feier&shy;lichen Er&shy;öff&shy;nungen in Reim&shy;form bis hin zur freien Trau&shy;rede für Braut&shy;paar und Hoch&shy;eits&shy;gäste. Doch nicht nur die freudigen Er&shy;eig&shy;nisse des Lebens, auch die leisen und trau&shy;rigen Töne gehören natürlich dazu. JA-Wort geben, eine stande&shy;samtliche Ehe&shy;schließung ersetzt die freie Trauung allerdings nicht.</p>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a small script which demonstrates how you can use jQuery to detect mouse wheel scroll up/down and perform functions based off of that:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).bind('mousewheel', function(e){
    if(e.originalEvent.wheelDelta /120 > 0) {
      $('#textbox').animate({
        'marginLeft' : "+=30px" //moves left
      });
    }
    else {
      $('#textbox').animate({
        'marginLeft' : "-=30px" //moves left
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/0xynbdvc/